# Execute Shell commands from an Android App

Tags: android

I am new to java programming and android development. I am working on an app that executes shell commands specifically the command:

```
su -c cat /sys/kernel/debug/asoc/*-snd-card*/*_codec*/codec_reg
```

I am using the following line for this purpose:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su", "-c", 
         "cat /sys/kernel/debug/asoc/*-snd-card*/*_codec*/codec_reg \n"});
```

I am able to run it fine on Android version 4.4.4 but not on the Lollipop versions. Apparently, there seems to be some root access problem.

Is there any way to run this command on Lollipop version?

Answer (score 0):

[LibSuperuser](https://github.com/Chainfire/libsuperuser) is a good tool to implements what you need. The how-to hosted [here](http://su.chainfire.eu/) explains exactly why you shouldn't use getRuntime().exec(), and use libsuperuser instead.

Enjoy :-)

Comment: Thank you! I am going through it!

Comment: Hi, I just used the command   "setenforce 0" after I had rooted my device. It seemed to work for me.